# MYSQL syntax error in CONVERT function

Tags: mysql

I have some problem in MYSQL syntax

This statement is work correctly

```
CONVERT(_latin1 'SOME-AR-TEXT' USING utf8));
```

But i don't need the `'SOME-AR-TEXT'` value, i need the value of some variable.

In other words, i tried to do this

```
CONVERT(_latin1 (SELECT some_variable) USING utf8));
```

But the console display syntax error.

What can i do to get the value of `some_variable` variable.

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONVERT(some_variable USING UTF8) AS field_value
  FROM MyTable
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'sub_keywords USING UTF8) AS field_value

Comment: But i need _latin1 :(

Comment: @EyadFarra  What you're trying to do doesn't really make sense:   converting column data first to one character set, and then to another.  Doing this obviates the advantages of unicode, and practically guarantees data loss.  What character set are you using?  (`SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM  MyTable`)

Answer (score 0):

By your SQL fiddle it seems like you want to convert each field. Why not just create the table with default charset latin? In that way, you would not have to specifially convert each field.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `example` (
  `some_variable` varchar(30) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

And there is something wrong the terminology as well. 'some_variable" isn't really a variable but a column/field in the database-table example.